Do the Xbox achievements synchronise between PC and Xbox Series S?
I recently got an Xbox Series S. This is my first ever Xbox console. Until then, I was using the PC app on my laptop to play as many games as available on the Game Pass.
I recently saw that my Gamerscore increased from some 0 to 12k units, a few days after I logged in to my new console. This was just from installing a few "Xbox Play Anywhere" games.
Now, I want to synchronise the trophies of all games (that support "Xbox Play Anywhere") that I had played on the PC Xbox app with the Series S. Does it happen automatically, or do I have to install each game (with Xbox "Play Anywhere") and synchronise it by playing it for a bit?

Xbox Achievements and Gamerscore are linked to your Microsoft/Xbox account. If you play on a platform connected online, they are automatically synced and available on all the other platforms, including Xbox consoles.
To check if your progress has been synced you can check your online profile here:
https://www.xbox.com/play/user
